# How to plot a horizontal line on the 30m and 5m chart

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am using split screen within Trading View, my default timeframe is the 30m, and I have a secondary timeframe (5m).

On the 30m chart (where the indicator is loaded), this function works as expected, and plots a horizontal line.

```
upperlimit = close[1] - (close[1] - low[2] )
line.new(bar_index - 2, upperlimit, bar_index, upperlimit, color = lgrLevelColor, extend = extend.right)
```

How can I also draw the same line on the 5m chart? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `security()` to ensure that the calculation is always done on the data from 30m timeframe. Otherwise, it will follow your chart's timeframe.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)

upperlimit = close[1] - (close[1] - low[2])

upperlimit_30m = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "30", upperlimit)

if (barstate.islast)
    line.new(bar_index - 2, upperlimit_30m, bar_index, upperlimit_30m, color = color.green, extend = extend.right)
    label.new(bar_index + 2, upperlimit_30m, str.tostring(timeframe.period) + ': ' + str.tostring(upperlimit_30m), color=color.new(color.white, 100), textcolor=color.white, style=label.style_label_left)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @vitruvius, is this the same in reverse? As in, the lines already show on the 30m, but I want to show them on the 5m.

Comment: I have added:

var upperLimit = close[1] - (close[1] - low[2])
var upperLimit_5m = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "5", upperLimit)

And then:

 line.new(bar_index - 2, upperlimit_5m, bar_index, upperlimit_5m, color = lgrLevelColor, extend = extend.right)

But I can't see any visible lines on the 5m (when there are lines plotted on the 30m)

Comment: If I remove `var` from the variable initialisation, it prints lots of extra lines on the 30m, but still, none on the 5m.